# How to fix variable is not defined` - The variable in question is clearly defined in my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, trello

Hey amazing people of the Internet,
Pretty noobish question here, but I'm having a bit of a problem with some of this Javascript I wrote. Here's the code -

```
const req0 = http.request({
      hostname: `api.trello.com`,
      port: 443,
      path: `/1/lists/5cb77e9ef180dd2bbb25acf2/cards?key=${trelloKey}&token=${trelloToken}&fields=name`,
      method: `GET`
    }, res => {
      let str = '';
      res.on('data', chunk => {
        str += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        try {
            var level0Data = JSON.parse(str);
            console.log(`Level 0: ${level0Data}`)
            level0Data.forEach((k,v) => {
                var id = k.id;
                var name = k.name;
                console.log(`${id} = ${name}`);
            });
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
      });
    });
    req0.on('error', error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    req0.end();


  level0Data.forEach(function(level0Names) {
    // code here
  });
```

The issue I'm having with this is that it keeps giving me an error stating that the `level0Data is not defined`.
I know it's a pretty newbie question, but I'd appreciate some guidance with it.
Thanks!

Comment: it's a problem of scope - the variable is defined inside `res.on('end', () => {` ... outside that, it is not defined - and even if that variable was defined in an outer scope, it would still be empty at the point where it is now undefined - due to asynchrony

Comment: If I put a bike in a house in another country, can you ride that bike in your place? The variable is not a global variable, it is inside a function, inside a try-statement....

Comment: see how you're doing `level0Data.forEach((k,v) => {` ... why don't you put `// code here` in that loop too?

Comment: @some - do you have a global bike I can ride? :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Nope, but I got an electric scooter yesterday, so if you come to Sweden, and are nice, I may let you try it :p

Comment: declare `level0Data` globally on top `var level0Data = {}`

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Better to process everything in the *end*-event-handler.

Comment: try node-fetch module. It's easier. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: @some and Jaromanda X - Thank you for the advice. I will try putting all the code into the end-event handler.

Comment: Even if you had declared  the variable globally, it would not have helped you. The data isn't available until you have received all the data and the end-event has been fired. The code where you have problem executes before the request has finished.

Comment: @some Worked like a charm - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see that `level0Data` is not defined in below scope? [(MDN reference(Scope))](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

```
  level0Data.forEach(function(level0Names) {
    // code here
  });
```

You must use `level0data` inside of callback function.

```
// NOTE: Level0data is available only here, as you defined in this scope.
...

            var level0Data = JSON.parse(str);
            console.log(`Level 0: ${level0Data}`)
            level0Data.forEach((k,v) => {
                var id = k.id;
                var name = k.name;
                console.log(`${id} = ${name}`);
            });

...
```

Or you can pass a function to handle callback.

```
function handle(str) {
            var level0Data = JSON.parse(str);
            console.log(`Level 0: ${level0Data}`)
            level0Data.forEach((k,v) => {
                var id = k.id;
                var name = k.name;
                console.log(`${id} = ${name}`);
            });

  level0Data.forEach(function(level0Names) {
    // code here
  });
}

...

try {
  handle(str)
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```